# Python program to flatten an array of ints

Tags: python, list, recursion, int, pseudocode

Given a list of ints which could have more lists of ints, we should return a flatten list.

For example:

- `flat_list([1, [2, 2, 2], 4])` returns `[1, 2, 2, 2, 4]`
- `flat_list([-1, [1, [-2], 1], -1])` returns `[-1, 1, -2, 1, -1]`

I have thought the pseudocode as follows:

```
if input_list length is 1
   return input_list

for i, number in input_list
   if number is an int
     return [number] + flat_list(input_list[i+1:])
   if number is a List
     return flat_list(input_list[i+1:]
```

**I have difficulties because of I do not know how to persist the list we build between each recursive call.**

To be specific I have difficulties with the line:

```
return [number] + flat_list(input_list[i+1:])
```

Because I think returning the number as `[number]` won't create the desired output.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: no, it's not

Comment: I have solved the exercise thanks to @Xolve who replies here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists